# How to change the port of the spring boot h2 console

Tags: java, spring-boot, h2

I am trying to view the spring boot h2 console. However, the default port is 8080, and that port is already being used on my machine.

Is there a way for me to change the web port that spring boot uses for h2? There's a lot of documentation around changing the path, but I can't find anything about changing the port. This is my current config set up:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:testdb
spring.datasource.driverClassName=org.h2.Driver
spring.datasource.username=sa
spring.datasource.password=password
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
spring.h2.console.enabled=true
spring.h2.console.settings.web-allow-others=true
spring.jpa.database=h2
```

**EDIT**
As mentioned by Atul K below, the h2 web console is available on the configured `server.port`. However, this isn't an option for me as our spring boot application performs mandatory header validation for all requests coming to the spring boot app. Is it possible to independently configure a port for the h2 web console and the spring boot app?

Comment: To answer your second question, one solution would be to start 2 spring boot applications. First boot app with embedded H2 (server.port=9090) and Second boot app (server.port=8081), and in second boot app, can configure first boot app with port 9090. Ref: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-access-h2-database-multiple-apps

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Add `server.port=8081` to your config. As its embedded, should use the same port of that of service. So should be able to access it using url: http://localhost:8081/h2-console

Answer (score 2):

For instance, you app yml config:

```
#tomcat
server.port: 7999

#h2
spring:
  h2:
    console.enabled: true
```

Start app and h2-console is available on 7999 port
[image]